# Is running PHP & MySQL on a Mac different to Ubuntu/Windows

Tags: php, mysql, macos, ubuntu, platform

I've never used a Mac for developing PHP Apps. I'm more of an Ubuntu person. So I'd like to know if installing & running AMP applications on a Mac is different.

For example, if I were to compare Ubuntu with Windows, here are some differences.

1. You have to enclose php code within `<?php ?>` all the time for Windows, but on Ubuntu you can use `<? ?>`
2. On Windows, when you name a database table as tblMyTable, it changes into tblmytable (all lowercase).
3. Crons are differently specified on Windows and Ubuntu.
4. File names on Ubuntu are case-sensitive but not on Windows.

So like this, I want to know if Ubuntu and the Mac AMP applications are different in terms of installation/operation.

Comment: Ubuntu and Mac should be pretty much exactly the same if Apache, PHP, and MySQL are built and configured the same way.

Comment: Crons are not related to PHP! They only exist in Linux/Unix systems. I don't know any Windows crontab implementation. Windows has its own Task Scheduler, which is a completely different feature.

Comment: What do you mean built and configured? I'm looking at if a user with default settings tries to install a php app on his Mac... I'm not expecting any self builds... So where do we stand in this regard?

Comment: You can also adjust `my.ini` mysql config file to adjust database name case-sensitivity.

Comment: @ahmet alp balkan, perhaps my use of the term 'cron' was mileading. I know how to schedule a php job on both Windows and Mac. I only gave it as an example. My question is if it is different on MacOS.

Comment: Mac OS X has the same crontab system with Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache and PHP are the same but different operating systems (or distributions of Linux) may come with different php.ini files. I would advise against using short tags (`<?` or `<?=`) if you're planning on switching platforms or hosts as it's a configurable option.

MySQL is a different story. It stored data differently on Windows, OS X and Linux. The table names are case sensitive on Linux but not on Windows and OS X. It's actually a little more complicated than that. Have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html for all the details.

OSX can be case sensitive or not, depending on how the partition was formatted. Most OS X installation are case-insensitive. Linux distributions are definitely case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

1. This is actually decided by a setting in your php.ini. Setting `short_open_tag = On` will allow you to use the short open tag "<?" instead of the long tag "<?php" on any PHP, regardless of operating system. For best portability, try to always use long tags. This includes avoiding the echo shortcut "<?=$var?>"
2. Francois' link to MySQL docs was perfect (+1): [Identifier Case Sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)
3. OS X comes with cron just like Linux. You can view your crontab with `crontab -l` and edit with `crontab -e`
4. It's good practice to be consistent about your filename case, whether or not the operating system enforces it.